# Надо ли ставить запятую в следующих примерах?

Tags: пунктуация

В скобки я поставил, те знаки препинания которые я хотел бы проверить на правильность их позиции.

Так же (,) Пётр стоит за свою и Машину честь....

Да и вообще (,) Пушкин, писав этот роман, вложил благодарность....

Так же (,) немаловажной частью характера были слова....

По мимо этого (,) можно заметить....

И плюсом к этому (,) он не употребил имя Маши в суде (,) дабы она не была вмешена в это....

Так же (,) этим поступком он пытался не запятнать имя Маши....

Я употребил слово (")честь (") (,) именно (,) потому что...

Надеюсь (,) вы поняли моё мнение....

Answer (score 1):

> В скобки я поставил, те знаки препинания которые я хотел бы проверить
>   на правильность их позиции.
>
> Так же (,) Пётр стоит за свою и Машину честь....
>
> Да и вообще (,) Пушкин, писав этот роман, вложил благодарность....
>
> Так же (,) немаловажной частью характера были слова....
>
> По мимо этого (,) можно заметить....
>
> И плюсом к этому (,) он не употребил имя Маши в суде (,) дабы она не
>   была вмешена в это....
>
> Так же (,) этим поступком он пытался не запятнать имя Маши....
>
> Я употребил слово (")честь (") (,) именно (,) потому что...
>
> Надеюсь (,) вы поняли моё мнение....

Попробую помочь - Вы же честно попытались побороться с русским языком, найдите теперь N различий.

---

*В скобки я поставил те знаки препинания, правильность которых хотел бы проверить.*

---

*Так же Пётр стоит за свою и Машину честь...* (Здесь слитное или раздельное "так же" зависит от контекста; раздельно, если этой фразе предшествовало упоминание ещё чего-то, где Пётр иначе проявлял бы принципиальность, защищал или выгораживал Машу. Вообще на сочинение многовато этих "также".)

*Да и вообще Пушкин, пишучи этот роман, выразил благодарность...* (Деепричастие от глагола "писать" трудно образовать, не вступая в противоречие с каким-либо из словарей.)

*Также немаловажной частью характера были слова...* (Э? Слова как часть характера? Переписать!)

*Помимо этого, можно заметить...*

*Плюс к этому он не произнёс имя Маши в суде, дабы она не была вмешана в это...* (Второе "это" заменить на что именно.)

*Также этим поступком он пытался не дать запятнать имя Маши...*

*Я употребил слово "честь" именно потому, что...*

*Надеюсь, вы поняли моё мнение...*

Comment: Хочу добавить к замечаниям Галины:1.Вместо "Стоит за свою и Машину честь"лучше употребить "защищает";2.не "писав", а "написав"; 3.вместо "вмешана" - "замешана в этом"; 4. последняя фраза довольно странная, неэтичная, такое впечатление, что Вы считаете того, кто это будет читать, тупым. Лучше просто сделать вывод, вернувшись к проблеме: Таким образом, Пётр Гринёв предстаёт перед нами человеком чести, исполнившим наказ отца "береги честь смолоду".